# Apache .htaccess Redirect from /something* to /something*.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In order to handle some legacy URLs from and old CMS, to point the old URLs to hard HTML backups of the corresponding pages, I need to set up a rule that redirect/rewrites`/fixedname_[id]` to `/fixedname_[id].html`, or load the actual .html file under the legacy URL (which is without .html).

For example Redirect `/druckfrisch_2016_15` to `/druckfrisch_2016_15.html`

OR

Load `/druckfrisch_2016_15.html` under the URL `/druckfrisch_2016_15`

---

If I use `RedirectMatch 301 /druckfrisch_(.*) /druckfrisch_$1\.html` 
It goes to

`/druckfrisch_2016_15.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html`

Some kind of recursive error? The destination address gets rewritten too, again and again? Do I need to exclude any URL containing `.html` in the first part of the query?

I've also tried these with no luck:

`RedirectMatch "/druckfrisch_(.*)" "/druckfrisch_$1\.html"`

`Redirect "^/druckfrisch_(.*)$" "/druckfrisch_$1\.html"`

`RewriteRule ^/druckfrisch_(.*)$ /druckfrisch_$1\.html`

Whatever new rules I add need to play nice with the default Wordpress .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I first exclude  `html` files with `RewriteCond` the `RewriteRule` works, and I don't need to scape the `.` as `\.` in the second part of the rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html)$
RewriteRule ^druckfrisch_(.+)$ /druckfrisch_$1.html [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```